# Session/EntityManager Closed when using StoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm getting an error

> IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed

when using `StoredProcedureQuery` with Oracle stored procedure and `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

Using Spring Boot + spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public class HibernateTestingDao implements CommandLineRunner {

...

    /**
     * Conector con la base de datos
     */
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Properties
     */
    @Autowired
    private CustomYMLFile properties;

    /**
     * Ejecucion automatica
     */
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        log.info("Iniciando la Ejecucion");

        procedureSalidaCursor();

        log.info("La ejecucion del proceso ha finalizado");

    }

    /**
     * Salida Cursor
     */
    private void procedureSalidaCursor() {

        log.info("Conectando al procedure : " + properties.getProcedureSalidaCursor());

        try {


            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            java.sql.Date fechaQuery = new java.sql.Date(df.parse("2017-07-17").getTime());

            StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
                    /*
                     * Procedure a llamar
                     */
                    .createStoredProcedureQuery(properties.getProcedureSalidaCursor())
                    /*
                     * Entradas
                     */
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    /*
                     * Salidas
                     */
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)

                    /*
                     * Parametros de entrada
                     */
                    .setParameter(1, fechaQuery) // FECHA
                    .setParameter(2, "77647538"); // RUT

            log.info("Ejecutando Procedure");
            query.execute();
            log.info("Procedure Ejecutado");

            List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

            log.info("Parametros obtenidos correctamente");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error al consultar BD , Detalle > ", e);
        }
    }
    ....
  }
```

I got the exception when I'm doing this:

```
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

If i use the same method but with procedures that has individual outputs everything is fine. but i got this exception with cursors.

github project: https://github.com/betray32/HibernateSpring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove `query.execute();` 
from your code;
when using `REF_CURSOR` and to get the data you must use `query.getSingleResult()` or `query.getResultList();`
If there are output parameters, they must be accessed after this line. 
Use `query.execute()` or `query.executeUpdate()` when `resultSet` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Please also make sure this is running in same transaction.

```
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public List<Employee> get(String employeeId) {
```